# Autofac DI, type not assignable to service

Tags: dependency-injection, autofac

I simply cannot figure this out. Using Autofac with .Net core 2.0 and trying to resolve some simple dependencies. Feel like I've tried everything so my current code doesn't reflect everything I've tried.

Here is one of the exceptions I'm getting from Autofac

> None of the constructors found with 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type 
>   'Elucidate.Core.Application.ValuesController' can be invoked with the available services and parameters: Cannot resolve parameter 'Elucidate.Core.Data.Repository.IRepository'1[Elucidate.Core.Model.User.IUser]rep' of constructor 'Void .ctor(Elucidate.Core.Data.Repository.IRepository`

Here is where I'm trying to get the dependency injected

```
public ValuesController(IRepository<IUser> rep)
```

Here is how I'm registering the types in an autofac module

```
builder.RegisterType<User>().As<IUser>();
builder.RegisterType<CoreUserStore<User>>();

builder.RegisterType(typeof(Repository<User>)).As<Repository<IUser>>();
builder.RegisterType<EntityFrameworkModelContext<User>>(); //.As<IModelContext>();
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm new to autofac, used to Unity which seems to be extinct.

Answer (score 3):

The `ValuesController` constructor is expecting `IRepository<IUser>` and you haven't wired the correct type in Autofac.

You need to register the concrete repository type as the implemented interface, note the `.As<IRepository...`:

```
builder.RegisterType(typeof(Repository<User>)).As<IRepository<IUser>>();
```

Or alternatively "ask" for the concrete type in the constructor.

```
public ValuesController(Repository<IUser> rep)
```

The first is probably the preferred approach. You can also do:

```
builder.RegisterType<Repository<User>>().AsImplementedInterfaces();
```

Which will register the concrete type as all implemented interfaces.

Comment: Thank you! I've tried this, but still get an exception that I can't quite get. Is the notation in double brackets troubling at all? Both of those concrete types definitely implement those interface.  


    ArgumentException: The type 'Elucidate.Core.Data.Repository.Repository`1[Elucidate.Core.Model.User.User]' is not assignable to service 
'Elucidate.Core.Data.Repository.IRepository`1[[Elucidate.Core.Model.User.IUser, Elucidate.Core.Model, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]'.

Comment: @JimPhelan, What you're dealing with now is a different problem; covariance. `Repository<User>` can't be assigned to the interface `IRepository<IUser>`, try it in code without Autofac, it will give you a compiler error. I would suggest you don't use `IUser`, and only register repositories around concrete types. Else, you can check out how to use covariance here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-generic-modifier

Comment: Thank you @xenolightning I've got it sorted after redesigning the interfaces a bit. I should have tried it without Autofac as you described first, made it pretty obvious once I did. Thanks again.